Getting: No Overload matches the Call. How do I resolve it?
I am not the best with Api calls. I am struggling with my api call I am trying call DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks. However it says that pCateLinksProd does "No overload matches the call". There are other calls being made in the same way but I am unsure why it is not allowing me to do it this way
TS:
DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks(pCatLinksProd: SxProdCatSubCatLinks) {
    return this.http.delete<boolean>(this.configService.getApiURI() +
      'Category/DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks/', pCatLinksProd)
      .pipe(map(emp => {
        return emp;
      }));
  }

CS:
public const string DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks = "/Category/DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks/";

Can anyone Help me?
I have tried to change the "'Category/DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks/', pCatLinksProd)" to "'Category/DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks/'+ pCatLinksProd)", however pCatLinksProd value is being read as [Object%20Object]

'Category/DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks/', pCatLinksProd should probably be 'Category/DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks/' + pCatLinksProd.id or both of 1. whatever your API expects (might be a UID or name, I don't know) 2. the correct property on pCatLinksProd that holds this value.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] the question to provide more details about your problem, preferably including a [mre] we can use to demonstrate it for ourselves in our own IDEs. If you can't do that then it's a lot harder for people to help you since we don't have your system in front of us... meaning you'd need to provide a lot more information so we can narrow it down.  In particular, we have no idea what SxProdCatSubCatLinks is (and neither do our IDEs), nor what url format the DeleteProdCatSubCatLinks endpoint expects after that last slash.
